# Passing variable from function A to main and back to another

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, program-entry-point

I have the following example

```
int main() {
    ...
}

void parameterList() {
    ...
}

void myMethodA() {
    ...
}

void myMethodB() {
    ...
}

void myMethodC() {
    ...
}
```

I have read several StackOverflow posts on this subject and understand to pass a variable from myMethodA() to myMethodB(), I will need to call myMethodB() in myMethodA() with the variables. To illustrate

```
void parameterList() {
    ...
    int someInteger = 45;
    string someName = "John";

    int otherInteger = 20;

    myMethodB(someName, someIntegers);
    myMethodC(otherInteger);
}

void myMethodB(string &someName, int &someInteger) {
    ...
    string another_someName = someName;
    int another_someInteger = someInteger;
    ...
}

void myMethodC(int &otherInteger) {
    ...
    int another_someInteger_two = otherInteger;
    ...
}
```

parameterList() is a function where it contains multiple variables for multiple myMethod() functions. On initial program run, parameterList() will have to run first in main to get all the necessary variable. Ideally, the main function will obtain all these variables from parameterList() and pass it to myMethod() in main function. To illustrate

```
Step 1
main function will run parameterList()

Step 2
parameterList() process and have multiple variables meant for multiple myMethod()

Step 3
main function should have a variable that can "store" these variables in order to pass it to all the myMethod() for further processing
```

The main function will not run myMethodB() until it is told to do so and when the variables from myMethodA() is inside the main.

Any clarification on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: If you cannot pass by reference or return some container that holds the data as return value then you have to use global variables (which is a bad practice)

Comment: Whats the context? Why not initialize them in main and pass by reference to A which in turn passes by reference to B?

Comment: myMethodA() is assume to be a file that contains all the necessary data parameters for other myMethodN functions (imagine there are > 5 myMethod - myMethodB, myMethodC and so on). Each of this myMethodN need some data parameter from myMethodA().

Comment: @SunnyBoiz so, you mean that the data for each function may be differ? Roughly, `methodD()` would want `var4` and not `var1`, `var2`, ...?

Comment: That is correct. My bad if the initial post is not clear.

Comment: `'John'` is invalid, string literals are created with `"`.

Comment: @KamilCuk corrected. Also modified my question to make it clearer of the issue.

Comment: The 2 answers to this are both valid and I have done either.  In the case you provide here, there are many ways to solve the problem.  Additionally, there are some decent suggestions in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

> Passing variable from function A to main and back to another

To pass a value out of a function, you can return it.

To pass a value into a function, you can use a parameter. Example:

```
int myMethodA() {
    int someInteger = 45;
    // ...
    return someInteger;
}

int main()
{
    int someInteger = myMethodA();
    myMethodB(someInteger);
}
```

---

> I don't think this will work if myMethodA() will need to return more than 1 variable

That's not a problem. While only one object can be returned, that object can be of a class type, and classes can contain more than one sub object. Example:

```
struct example {
    int someInteger;
    string someName;
};

example myMethodA();

void myMethodB(const example&);
```

If it makes sense for the structure of the program, the functions could potentially be made member functions of the class such as demonstrated in KamilCuk's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62982814/2079303).

---

> Can the struct have array?

Yes. Class members can be arrays.

> Is 'example myMethodA()', is that in the main function?

That is a declaration of a function that returns instance of `example`.

> How should I return these variables in myMethodA() inside myMethodA() return?

Same way as you return other objects. With the `return` statement.

Comment: So, you're trying to return an integer to a void function and assigning the returned value into an integer in `main()`. How's that possible?

Comment: @RohanBari There was a bug. Not anymore.

Comment: Thanks eeorika, I don't think this will work if myMethodA() will need to return more than 1 variable (it will return multiple int, string and perhaps an array or two).

Comment: Thanks eeorika. I am currently attempting your suggestion but need to understand a thing or two. Can the struct have array? Is 'example myMethodA()', is that in the main function? Because I don't think I can have int myMethodA() if myMethod() consists of string, int, array. How should I return these variables in myMethodA() inside myMethodA() return?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a class to wrap data and also manage the lifetime of the objects.

```
class Context {
    int someInteger;
    string someName;

    Context(int a, const string& b) :
       someInteger(a),
       someName(b)
       {}

    void myMethodA() {
        /* do something with someInteger and someName */
    }

    void myMethodB() {
       /* do something with the results from myMethodA */
    }
};

int main() {
    Context ctx{45, "John"};
    ctx.myMethodA();
    ctx.myMethodB();
}
```